# Xarray time coordinate from integer to datetime

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray, dtype

I have a NetCDF datafile which I read in with xarray.

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
dataDIR = myNetCDFdatafile
DS = xr.open_dataset(dataDIR)
DS
```

shows the dataset's structure:

[image]

As you can see. time is of int32 type. Thhis integer number represents a time stamp of seconds since 1970-01-01. The period of this time stamps is not equally spaced.

How can I convert it to datetime type?

If I try the numpy way

```
DS.time = DS.time.astype('datetime64')
```

I do get a

```
ValueError: datetime64/timedelta64 must have a unit specified
```

Any hint?

Comment: "datetime64/timedelta64 must have a unit specified" is a pretty decent hint :) see the numpy docs on [datetime units](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units). what are the units on `time`? numpy doesn't know what to do with these values without encoding information. there might be a clue in the attributes - can you access `ds.time.attrs` or click on the little attributes page icon in the xarray preview to see if there is a description of the units and calendar?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado sorry for the late response: Corona knocked me down... `ds.time.attrs` results in: (time) int32. My aim is a date format like YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss. is there a more direct way than going over `strftime`?

Answer (score 0):

do you know what those time values stands for? 1647475208 for example?
Sometimes this kind of values represents seconds or days from X date. If you know the min, max and frequency of the time variable you can use pd.data_range()

something like this:

```
ds['time'] = pd.date_range('2001-01-01', '2010-12-31', freq = 'D') #for a daily interval for example
```

Comment: '@Ruben-Calvo: thanks. the time value stands for seconds since 01.01.1970. The frequency usually is seconds but not always equally spaced all the day long: sometimes there are a few seconds missing... I will try your proposal. I did not find a soliution how to tell pandas that the period is not equally spaced.

Comment: Maybe something based on this could help: ```import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
import xarray as xr
times = []
for i in range(100):
    times.append(pd.to_datetime('2001-01-01')+timedelta(seconds = i))

times = pd.Series(times)
ds = xr.Dataset()
ds['time'] = times```